# SQL Server Merge using Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have a dataframe that I want to merge back to a SQL table - not merge in the pandas sense, which would be a join, but a SQL merge operation to update/insert records into the table based on a comparison between the dataframe and the table.

There are a few work arounds I can see, such as writing the dataframe to a new table and doing the merge in SQL, or deleting any existing records based on the primary keys and appended the whole dataframe to the table using `to_sql` - but is there any built in function that would do this sort of merge in python directly?

Comment: Personally, I’d do the merge in DataFrames.  One with your current dataset and another DataFrame with your existing SQL table.  Merge those and then push back into a new temp SQL table.  (Than handle the table drop/replace in SQL).

Comment: I'm also looking for a reference to do the same... but I don't think its good idea to delete/drop records/table at your target. What if you end up with some issue in between and end up loosing the data?

Comment: I think its better to dump the data to an intermediate table in SQL DB, and then do a MERGE (or an SP with MERGE) by calling from python.

Comment: Databricks has a neat implementation - https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#upsert-into-a-table-using-merge - it'd be great if there was something like this in Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

The concat function in pandas allows one to accomplish something similar to a merge.

I encountered a similar issue and was able to develop a function that "merges" two dataframes assuming a shared index. In my case, I turned a field "PrimaryKey" into the index for each dataframe and then merged the two dataframes using this field.

```
import pandas as pd

        def merge_dataframe_diff(target_df, source_df, merge_on_fields: [list] = ["PrimaryKey"], drop_index: [bool] = True)):
            """Merges two dataframes based on shared columns
            Assumptions:
                1) The dataframes share all the same columns
                2) There is a "PrimaryKey" column to merge on; this could be modified to include multiple columns
            Args:
                source_df [dataframe]: source dataframe
                target_df [dataframe]: target dataframe (to merge/upsert into)
                merge_on_fields [list]: field(s) to merge the two dataframes on
                drop_index [dataframe]: whether to drop the merge_on_fields from the merged dataframes and the returned dataframe

            Returns:
                full_df [dataframe]: merged dataframe
            """
            source_df.set_index(merge_on_fields, drop=drop_index, append=False, inplace=True, verify_integrity=True)  # Set Pk to index to enable merging
            target_df.set_index(merge_on_fields, drop=drop_index, append=False, inplace=True, verify_integrity=True)
            full_df = pd.concat([target_df[~target_df.index.isin(source_df.index)], source_df])  # SQL merge aka upsert the two dfs using index as "merged on" field          
            full_df = diff_df  # it is assumed to be the first run and the source dataframe is returned
            if drop_index:
                full_df.drop(columns=merge_on_fields, inplace=True)
            return full_df
```